# issues in implementing firebase crash analytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, android-app-indexing

I am trying to implement firebase crash analytics for my android app I added the dependencies as as shown in firebase site,I also added the googleservices.json. Now after making changes I installed my map and it crashes.

I have attached screenshot[image: logcat image] of logcat. Please help me.

**build.gradle of app**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.quotesapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0")
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0")
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


}
```

Comment: Add some of your code sample, from where you are getting this crash

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh the app crashes after opening itself

Comment: Add some of your code implementation with question, then only i will be able to know that what you are doing wrong

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh i have no clue of what code to add

Comment: @AvinashKumarSingh the error is haappening after implementation of firebase crash analytics ,just point out any section from logcat code i will share the code

Comment: Please share your app build.gradle file

Comment: @Hascher i have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

After

```
buildFeatures {

}
```

add

```
compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Also add

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
```

Also in your project build.gradle if you have not added

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0'
```

in dependencies then do so